# phpMyAdminの composerを利用したインストールについて

Tags: phpmyadmin

[composerでのインストールの説明ページ](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/ja/latest/setup.html#installing-using-composer)
を参考にしてインストールしたのですが、js/dist/ が空のままで、メインページ表示時に複数のファイルが読み出せず正常にページを開く事が出来ません。
create-project の実行後、何か追加の作業が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: 実行環境の情報 (OS や PHP のバージョン等) や、コマンドを実行した際の詳しい手順 (どのディレクトリ/フォルダでコマンドを実行した等)、なるべく詳しい情報を含めておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: 「composerでのインストール」の記述に従い
composer create-project phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
を実行しました。
PHPのバージョンは 7.4です。
composerでのインストールにOSやディレクトリが影響するとは考え難いですがが、Debian10のユーザーホームディレクトリ（他のディレクトリでも変わらず）です。
create project で行っているので .jsonはありません。